# Store video files on internal or sd card memory with protection?

Tags: android, video, filesystems, sd-card

I have an issue with my app .I want some video files to be stored in sdcard or internal memory  in such a way that it could be read only by my app.

And other app may not read or copy the videos.Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The most protection you're going to get is through packaging the data with your app. Even this won't protect the files if the device is rooted. All other storage areas are exposed to browsing by the user.